# String in Core Java

Tags: java, string, substring

Whenever String has a Character `'e'`,`'m'`,',Then it should insert `"s"`,`"d"`,after that character Respectively.
2.Whenever it finds blank space it should print the length of the word.(Before and After appending both cases) 3.`'j'` Should be Replaced by `'k'` in the String.

And the String input is from user.

For Case 1 & 2 i am thinking to use StringBuilder. But not sure how to implement it.

Can Anyone help me?

And the String input is from user.
Can Anyone help me?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class strReplace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the String : ");
        String str = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        String str1 = str.replace('a', '@');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give example of 2.Whenever it finds blank space it should print the length of the word.

Comment: @GauravJeswani Example :Input :  "who can answer" output : who 3 can 3 answer 6

Comment: see my  modified answer below for #3

Comment: And the length should be considered before replacement or after replacement of point1?

Comment: @GauravJeswani Not sure how to do for both cases. before appending and after appending the chars. If you Could show for both cases it will helpful!

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 3):

Apply my pseudo code:

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
int prevSpaceIndex = 0;
 for each character in this string
      case 'e','m','t','i': :
        //append character at `i` and the following special character.
        break;
        case 'a':
           //append '@' in this case.
           break;
        case ' ':
           //append length of word and reset it.
           break;
      default: 
        //append to output for other cases.
        break;
```

---

I removed my implementation regarding below comment. Just give you an idea.

Comment: @Stultuske: do you think I copied my answer from somewhere:D? Show me the original post.

Comment: @Stultuske, I got you. I don't do all the thing for him. It's not a completed solution.

Comment: the only thing missing to be complete is the treatment of m, t and i, as far as I can see. In order to add that, you don't really need to know what you are doing. Do you also know what remark would be given during a code review?

Comment: removed my implementation :-)

Comment: You should also remove the String.valueOf. StringBuffer has an append which takes a char

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below:

1) Replace the characters

2) Calculate Length recursively

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    // Take input from user, using scanner
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the String : ");
    String a= sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    //Replace the characters
    a = a.replaceAll("e", "e#");
    a = a.replaceAll("m", "m$");
    a = a.replaceAll("t", "t%");
    a = a.replaceAll("i", "i&");
    a = a.replaceAll("a", "@");

    final int startIndex = 0;

    final int indexOfSpace = a.indexOf(" ");

    //Length calculation after replacement
    if (indexOfSpace > 0) {
      a = replaceSpaceWithLength(a, startIndex, indexOfSpace);

    }

    System.out.println(a);

  }

  private static String replaceSpaceWithLength(String s, int startIndex, int indexOfSpace) {

    s = s.substring(0, indexOfSpace) + " " + (indexOfSpace - startIndex) + " "
        + s.substring(indexOfSpace + 1, s.length());

    int length = indexOfSpace - startIndex;
    startIndex = indexOfSpace + 2;

    // Calculate the total number in previous words, if 5 it's 1 and if 15 it's 2
    do {

      length = length / 10;

      ++startIndex;

    } while (length % 10 > 1);

    indexOfSpace = s.indexOf(" ", startIndex);

    if (indexOfSpace > 0) {
      s = replaceSpaceWithLength(s, startIndex, indexOfSpace);
    } else {

      // Else condition for last word, as there is no space
      final int lengthOfLastWord = s.length() - startIndex;

      s = s + " " + lengthOfLastWord;
    }

    return s;
  }
```

**Input :** hello world!!!!!!!

**Output :** he#llo 6 world!!!!!!! 12

Note : You can take user input using scanner. And As I have used String performance won't be great, but good to start with for you.